# How to best represent database views/summary info in "3-Tiered" application

Tags: view, soa, dto, n-tier-architecture

This is basically asking the same question as in [How to handle views in a multilayer-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988646/how-to-handle-views-in-a-multilayer-application). However, that post didn't receive much feedback.

Here's the problem: we have built a 3-tiered web application with the following tiers:

-Data Access (using repositories)  
-Service  
-UI (MVC 3)

DTO's are passed between the UI (Controller) Layer and Service Layer. Heavier Domain Models, containing a lot of domain-level logic, are passed between the Service and Data Access Layers. Everything is decoupled using IOC and the app follows SOLID principals (or tries too) --a big happy decoupled family!

Currently the DTO->Domain Model and Domain Model->DTO conversion happens all in the service layer.

So, finally to my question:

We are going to need to start displaying more complex read-only subsets of information, (i.e. summary views joining multiple entities doing rollup totals, etc). So what is the best practice for representing this type of read-only data in the n-tiered system? Having to map read-only Domain Model types to DTO types in this case doesn't make sense to me. In most cases, there would be no difference between the 2 types anyway. My thought would be to "break" the layering boundaries for these read-only types, having the Data Access Layer serve up the DTO's directly and pass those through to the Service Layer and on to the UI.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Much Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thought on breaking the layering for reading and then displaying values make sense completely. After all, the architecture/design of the system should help you and not the other way around.

Displaying report-like data to the user should be queried simply from the database and pushed to the view; no domain/dto conversion, especially if you're in a web app. You will save yourself a lot of trouble by doing this. 
Personally, I had some attempts to go through these mappings just to display some read only data and  it worked poorly; the performance, the unnecessary mappings, the odd things I had to do just to display some kind of report-like views. In this case, you'll likely have your domain model and a read model. You can look up CQRS pattern, it might guide you away from thinking that you want to use the same data model for both writes and reads.

So, to answer you question, I believe that in this case the best way would be to skip layering and read DTOs directly from the database through a thin layer.

Comment: Very nice - thank you for the link to CQRS, it seems like exactly the approach that I need! Having the repository build up the readonly views makes sense. There may be some violation of SRP as the repository/db may be handling what could be considered business logic when it comes to composing the data shapes (grouping, etc). However, there is in most cases performance & maintainability gains to offset that so-called violation, as you mentioned. I'd vote you up but the freakin site won't let me do that yet :)

Comment: I wouldn't use the same repositories to query for read data as the repository should server domain objects. Because of this, you won't get into trouble and the SRP police won't arrest you as you might have a different model for reading through a different read layer (repository or some sort of a query